# What's a good random dungeon generator for D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tool-recommendation, generator

I'm looking for a random dungeon generator for D&D 3.5.

I'd like a generator that looks like [Dizzy Dragon's](http://www.dizzydragon.net/adventuregenerator/gen), but specifically for D&D, but also with a theme or groups option (Like crypt, or only undeads - only demons etc).

I've searched quite a bit for a good dungeon generator, but didn't find any especially good.

These are the 'top' ones I've found:

[Myth-Weavers](http://www.myth-weavers.com/generate_dungeon.php) - Good, but no random room dressing / themes / encounter types;

[Tunnels & Trolls](http://www.apolitical.info/webgame/dungeon/index2) - Quite nice, but too many details, bad maps and not D&D specific;

[Dizzy Dragon](http://www.dizzydragon.net/adventuregenerator/start) - Almost perfect, but not D&D specific;

[Wizards](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/mapper/launcher.htm) - Good ideas, but not fully implemented yet (quite buggy in fact) , so half the features don't work.

I'd like to avoid generating anything manually, because of the concept of my game (everything is random, from character races/classes/alignment to adventure ideas).

Note: People say the [Donjon](http://donjon.bin.sh) one is pretty much what I'm looking for, but the site is offline. If anyone knows another place where that is hosted or a similar generator, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I don't remember the 3.5 DMG that specifically, but IIRC the 2ed DMG had a way to randomly generate dungeons via dice rolls.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that goes w/o saying. But I'd like that automatized...

Comment: Dizzy Dragon's *is* specifically for D&D, and it has a d20 setting…

Comment: Dizzy Dragon's is not specifically for D&D 3.5, not from seeing the results.

Comment: http://donjon.bin.sh/adnd/dungeon/ is up.

Answer (score 8):

I have used [Donjon](http://donjon.bin.sh/d20/dungeon/) myself, but not in a while. I just checked it, and the site is up. I find the site usable, but lacking.

Other Creator I have not used:

- [Wizards](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/mapper/launcher.htm)
- [Third Edition (3.5) Dungeons and Dragons Character Generator](http://dnd3rd.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: checked on Monday August 19th 2013, works fine.

Comment: Yeah donjon is still up.  http://donjon.bin.sh/adnd/dungeon/

Comment: I recommend Donjon as well.

Answer (score 4):

My site, [RPG20](http://rpg20.com/), has some utilities, one of them being a [dungeon generator](http://rpg20.com/dungeonGen.php). To be honest, I think it still has a long way to go before I *really* like it. But it gets the job done for the moment.

Donjon did release some source code, but for only for the [simple dungeon](http://rpg20.com/donjon.cgi).

I also keep a [list of tools](http://rpg20.com/about.php#others) (from other people) in my *about page*, but you already mentioned most of those that I consider to be among the best.

You missed the one at [Inkwell Ideas](http://www.inkwellideas.com/roleplaying_tools/random_dungeon/) though. That one seems to be very popular. It doesn't generate [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) stuff, but it has very nice graphics.

Comment: That list of tools is great. But about your dungeon generator, it generates only NPCs? I mean, no monsters like a basilisk or something?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't added that functionality. I do have a [monster database](http://rpg20.com/monsters.php) but I haven't yet included encounters into the dungeons.

Comment: @LucasFamelli, For the record: I recently added rudimentary monster encounters.

Comment: Hey dude, I'm checking it right now. In my PnP table I'm rolling everything (EVERYTHING) in front of the players, for this gag campaign we're playing, so that will be very useful ^^ (makes for awesome random encounters, like a aboleth in the middle of a desert oasis, carrying 3 magical swords)